# Collapsing Toolbar Layout does not show Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Collapsing Toolbar Layout does not show Toolbar when collapsed.What should i do?

I tried every way but it didnt work at the end.

Toolbar at the end does not appear it only shows a white blank layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/cardview_light_background"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="12dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/resim3"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Do you say that title of `toolbar` not visible? or Do you have any other issue?

Comment: toolbar is not vissible

Comment: Change your toolbar background color its showing

Answer (score 0):

Add Background of the toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="#ccc"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

From Java: You can set the back Button like this

```
 toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.backarrow);
```

Comment: If i give background than toolbar will appear before colapsing a situation which i dont want

Comment: umm, You can Put this Lines to get a toolbar.                                     ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Activity");

Comment: or else try to put the toolbar before the collapsingToolbar so that would be visible. :)